# How do I kick from my hip ?

Tags: training, swimming

I am trying to relearn swimming and notice the importance of kicking from the hip as being the most effective for propulsion and energy consumption. I have tried to imagine am kicking from my hip and I am not. I record myself doing a flutter kick and can see the kick really isn't originating from the hip but the knee. I have tried to visualise that my knee and ankle are made of rubber but it hasn't helped. Unfortunately, am a big guy and heavy at the waist.

Are there any exercises that can specifically help me make my kicks begin at the hip ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a swimmer but after searching on many website vertical flutter kicking is the best technique for improving kick and make kicks begin at the hip.

Article on [triathlete](http://www.triathlete.com/2014/04/training/saras-slam-are-kicking-sets-that-important_51206) has a conversation that mention these two drills for focusing on strengthening your core, glute and hip extensors.

> Extend Leg Drill
>   Swim with one leg extended out of water, then switch to the opposite leg after a 25.
>
> Vertical Kicking With Weight
>   Try vertical kicking sets holding a 1–5-pound object out of the water (10 rounds, 45 seconds kicking, 15 seconds off). “During this set, the legs are forced to kick with equal force and direction, while the core and shoulders contract in unison,”.

Article from [azcentral](http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/swim-hips-2730.html)

> Competitive swimmers typically utilize the two-beat cycle, kicking two times for each arm cycle -- essentially one kick per arm stroke. Another option is the six-beat cycle, in which you kick six times for each arm cycle. This is also called the flutter kick. Because it's so fast, it can be tougher to incorporate the hips with the six-beat cycle.

and many websites articles mention vertical kicking as the best way to improve hip kicking. Links to other website articles [UWhealth](http://www.uwhealth.org/news/five-common-freestyle-errors-and-how-to-fix-them/48086), [US MASTERS SWIMMING](http://www.usms.org/articles/articledisplay.php?aid=2996), [Swymnut Masters](http://swymnutmasters.com/training-tips/stroke-tips/get-hip-with-your-hips-in-freestyle/), [SEAHIKER](http://www.seahiker.com/how-to-kick-like-a-swimmer/) and [Enjoy Swimming](http://www.enjoy-swimming.com/flutter-kick.html).

**At last** Article from [SwimSmooth](http://www.swimsmooth.com/kick.html):

> A good way to think about kicking from your hips is to squeeze your bum when you kick. It's a bit crude, but imagine you have a large coin between your butt cheeks and you're trying to hold it there whilst you swim. Keep your knees relaxed and drive the kick from the hips.

**Note**: All the quotes are copied from the respective website and i'm not original author. If I have failed to mention any copyrighted material that is clearly my mistake.